Spring Jpa ignores the next ID value from sequence table
In the excel_line_seq sequence table the next_val is 20.
select * from excel_line_seq;
+----------+
| next_val |
+----------+
|        20 |
+----------+

But when I try to save a new entity with Spring Jpa repository, I see that id = 1, after save() invocation:
var excelLineEntity = new ExcelLineEntity();
excelLineEntity.setFileName("file1.txt");
excelLineEntity = excelLineRepository.save(excelLineEntity);

//actually it is not expected, id must be at least of value = 20 (or the next one)
Assertions.assertEquals(1, excelLineEntity.getId());

As a consequence, when I try to persist 2 entitites, I get the exception:

org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Just because Spring Jpa Repository tries to use the same id = 1 for both independent entities.
Jpa entity is defined with strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE for id:
@Entity
@Table(name = "excel_line")
public class ExcelLineEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  Long id;

  String fileName;

Spring Data Jpa repository is used to persist enties:
public interface ExcelLineRepository extends JpaRepository<ExcelLineEntity, Long> {}

MySql has no true sequences support, so excel_line_seq table is created and 20 is inserted as value. MySql output is above.
Notes:

the scheme is generated by liquibase
the scheme is validated by Spring Jpa with: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate property. The validation gets triggered. When the sequence table was not created, I got a validation error. So JPA definitely considers the excel_line_seq as the right table for id generation.
I tried to set explicitely sequence configuration as:

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "excelLineSequence")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "excelLineSequence", sequenceName = "excel_line_seq", allocationSize = 50)
  Long id;

But the result is the same.
What do I miss?
Must I explicitely calculate the next value from the sequence table to insert as id when I create a new entity? If the answer is yes, I must, then it sounds a bit strange.
Note: I am running integration tests, so it is not the case, when it happens with the running application and the next value might be stored by jpa.

Enable SQL logging and add logs to the question.

I'm not sure if anyone will meet this issue again, it is very specific, but hope it might help someone, cause the bahaviour of jpa was mystical to me.
2 solutions were applied to make it function properly.

The entity had not shown in the original question another field with @ManyToOne mapping configured:

  @ManyToOne
  @MapsId
  @JoinColumn(name = "another_entity_id")
  AnotherEntity anotherEntity;

And @MapsId attribute somehow affected jpa id generation for ExcelLineEntity.
I cannot explain it, why, and how at all it could be possible. But removing: @MapsId fixed an issue with the same id generation by JPA for each new entity.
So the solution was to configure mapping as:
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "another_entity_id")
  AnotherEntity anotherEntity;

And it solved the problem.
Another issue was with the initial value for the sequence generation.
When I set it to 20:
select * from excel_line_seq;
+----------+
| next_val |
+----------+
|        20 |
+----------+

The new id were generated with -29, -28, etc. id values.
Setting the initial next_val value to 1, made the generation of id, beginnning from 1, 2, 3, etc.
